# Cannot read property 'name' of null node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, aws-cloud9

***Schema***

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     name: String,
     image: String,
     description: String,
     _id: String
});

var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);

app.get("/campgrounds/:id",function(req , res){
    Campground.findById(req.params._id, function(err, foundCampgrounds){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render("show", {campground: foundCampgrounds});
        }
    });
});
```

***show.ejs***

```
<%- include('partials/header')  %> 
<h1>this is a show template</h1>
<p><%= campground.name %></p>
<img src="<%=campground.image%>">

<%- include('partials/footer')  %>
```

***error***

```
TypeError: /home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/views/show.ejs:3`
    1| <%- include('partials/header')  %> `
    2| <h1>this is a show template</h1>`
 >> 3| <p><%= campground.name %></p>`
    4| <img src="<%=campground.image%>">`
    5| 
    6| <%- include('partials/footer')  %>`
```

> Cannot read property 'name' of null
>       at eval (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/views/show.ejs:13:37)
>       at show (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:656:17)
>       at tryHandleCache (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
>       at View.render (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>       at /home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/app.js:74:17
>       at /home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4828:16
>       at /home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4390:12
>       at model.Query.Query._completeOne (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2074:12)
>       at Immediate.Query.base.findOne.call (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2136:10)
>       at Immediate. (/home/ec2-user/environment/Yelpcamp/v2/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:116:16)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)

i am getting this error even after restarting mongodb 
and how can i check if the name is null or not

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a result from mongoose? It seems foundCampgrounds is null. can you console.log it?

Comment: yeah it is showing that the foundCampgrounds is null ,but i can't understand why

Comment: Do req.params.id , not _ id

Comment: Lol yelpcamps..is it from some udemy course? I remeber it

Comment: thank you and yeah it is from udemy

Comment: and for those who are still getting error use

Comment: `var curid = req.params.id;`
    `curid = curid.replace(/\s/g,'');`

Comment: since i am having a blank space after the objectid. for more info search [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “undefined” at path “_id”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bruh it has to be req.params.id without underscores : )

Comment: Good answer but please provide a more professional oriented answer. Use examples and documentation sources to harden your point. Specifically more on the topic of request and params with different examples.

Comment: please add some explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. After restarting the server, open the "/campgrounds" page, which in my case is "http://localhost:3000/campgrounds"
2. Thereafter click on more info.

I also faced the same problem, but when I opened from /campgrounds page it was solved

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem is bit simple and it is in this line of code

`res.redirect("/campgrounds"{campground:newCampgrounds})`

You might be missing referencing the `newCampgrounds` to the campground that will be going to be used in the show.ejs as `campground.name` or `campground.image` so on..